# Airflow Debugging: setting max_active_runs causes limit for dag to be reached error

Tags: python, airflow

I setup Airflow to use the DebugExcecutor, and while experimenting, I set the DAGs `max_active_runs` property to 3. Now it seems as though I opened pandora's box.
All my subsequent runs complain that `INFO - max_active_runs limit for dag has been reached  - waiting for other dag runs to finish`

1. Removing the max_active_runs property doesn't fix this
2. Setting the max_active_runs=-1 doesn't fix this
3. Setting the max_active_runs=0 doesn't fix this
4. Incrementally increasing the max_active runs fixes it once, then I need to continually increment it and eventually I get this error:  `SAWarning: Reassigning polymorphic association for identity 'BackfillJob' from <Mapper at 0x10a067e50; BackfillJob> to <Mapper at 0x10a1588e0; BackfillJob>: Check for duplicate use of 'BackfillJob' as value for polymorphic_identity.`
5. Smashing my laptop doesn't fix this

This is annoying. What's going on? Clearly, I have active jobs that are not getting completed when I close the debugging session. How can I clear them (programmatically)?

In the end of the code I have this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dag.clear(reset_dag_runs=True)
    min_ago=timezone.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1)
    dag.run(start_date=min_ago)
```

Is my approach all wrong? Why is it this was not a problem until I set the argument once?

Comment: Which (by number) laptop are you writing from? 